# Generate random email address and hide form field

Tags: jquery

I have a form which requires a unique email address to be completed. I don't necessarily need people's email addresses though so my solution is to write a script which generates a dummy email address. The script should work like so:

- Click link to generate random email address (I've completed this)
- Email address gets populated in form field (I've completed this)
- Form field then gets hidden (Not completed, so the user doesn't edit the random email address)
- The link that generates random email address should do the opposite if clicked again (so the user can click the link again and the form field appears again but is empty, so the user can enter an actual email address if desired)

I just can't quite finish off the missing elements. Is anyone able to provide some help?

Here's a JSFiddle with what I've done: https://jsfiddle.net/faye4tj5/

```
<script>
    var randomemail = "@dummyaddress.com";
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000); 

    function setRandomEmail() { $('#email-field').val( randomnumber + randomemail ); }

        $('#random-hold').on('click','.generate-random', setRandomEmail);
</script>

<p id="random-hold" style="font-size:18px;font-weight:600;line-height:1;"><a class="generate-random" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">Click here to generate random email address</a></p>
<form>
<input type="text" id="email-field">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track whether the value is generated with a `data` attribute (ex: `<input ... data-generated="1" />`)

When generated you can set the input to `disabled` so that the user cannot change the value (ex: `<input ... disabled />`)

so the generated state for the input would look like:

```
<input type="text" id="email-field" name="email" 
    value="987239478@dummyaddress.com" data-generated="1" disabled>
```

clicking the button again would reset the input back to

```
<input type="text" id="email-field" name="email" value="">
```

[<kbd>jsfiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/koqctn4a/)

```
$('#random-hold').on('click','.generate-random', () => {
  let email = $('#email-field');
  if (email.data('generated') === '1') {
    email.val('');
    email.removeData('generated');
    email.removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    email.val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + "@dummyaddress.com");
    email.data('generated', '1');
    email.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you might consider doing all this *without jQuery*, using vanilla Javascript/ES6.

```
document.querySelector('.generate-random').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let email = document.myForm.email;
  if (email.getAttribute('data-generated') === '1') {
    email.value = '';
    email.removeAttribute('data-generated');
    email.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    email.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + "@dummyaddress.com";
    email.setAttribute('data-generated', '1');
    email.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: Stuck with the jQuery solution and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much.